# Magic Launcher wont let me log in

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

Hi Ive just downloaded the magic launcher, but when I enter my username and password (entering email address) it says incorrect details. But when I log into my mojang account, its right. Any ideas?

Comment: What is Magic Launcher? The non-pirated launcher should be the only one to be used.

Comment: Oh I see. I have not done much research into it, but I believe it is a mod loader. If you want mods, I recommend installing the regular Minecraft launcher, if you don't have it, then install Forge.

Comment: Yeah, Magic Launcher is one of the few launchers that isn't developed to use pirated copies of Minecraft or a cracked launcher. It's pretty slick, but I personally stick with the default to avoid any raised eyebrows and generally clean playing.

Answer (score 0):

Though best results for Minecraft is with the default launcher, sometimes people have a personal preference for something that best fits their style.

I'm not overly familiar with Magic Launcher because of the aforementioned but because it's not a cracked launcher, generally trusted by ethical players. Unfortunately there is no official site for this application so I wasn't able to direct you to any official support, however, the swath of support and tutorials for troubleshooting problems is wide with some even appearing on Minecraftforum.net and MinecraftSix, two places it can be obtained directly and are trusted among ethical players.

I did find a [YouTube](https://youtu.be/5Tpp_6GR_fg) video that specifically addresses the problem you're asking about.